# SSIS To Iterate Access Tables

Tags: ms-access, ssis

I have one database with about 10 different tables I want to import in one .dtsx package.  I can import 1 individual table without issue, my problem is I can't figure out how to set it up to iterate the tables.  I know it would be a foreach loop but which type, and how to specify the tables?  Can someone please assist with this?

EDIT ----
I am importing the single table with a data flow task.  Going Ole DB Source -- to -- Ole DB Destination. (From Microsoft Access To SQL Server)

EDIT #2 ------
How would I set up my SQL Statement to pull the data from more than one table?  I assume this is where the SQL Statement would go
[image]

Comment: How are you importing the 1 table?   With a dataflow, or object copy?

Comment: Yes - Data flow Task.  Editing Initial Post now.

Comment: Do the 10 tables have the same structure?

Comment: Yes - each table has the same data structure.

Comment: Upvoted for username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but you can try this:

1. Use an EXECUTE SQL task to populate a dataset with a list of the 10 tables you want to import.  If the table names are constant, the EXECUTE SQL can be as simple as:

   SELECT 'Table1' AS TableName
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Table2' 
   UNION ALL ...
2. ForEachLoop through that dataset, populating a @sql variable that you use in the SQL Query of your OLEDB source in your dataflow.  The @sql variable contains your entire SQL select, choosing the table name from the dataset you are looping through.  In your OLEDB Source, choose the "SQL Command From Variable" option for Data Access Mode.

Comment: how do I iterate the tables in the access database to create the dataset?

Comment: You don't iterate the tables, you iterate the table names.  Your OLEDB source will have to use a query, rather than a table.